# compiling a clang plugin

Tags: c++, clang, clang-plugin

I'm trying to learn how to use clang plugins. When I used the example code for a plugin and tried to compile it using Makefile (I prefer it better than cmake) it compiled fine but in linking stage it says that it could not find the clang libraries I'm stuck if any of you know that what I'm doing wrong please help me

I'm using the default example in the clang [Attribute.cpp](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/clang/examples/Attribute/Attribute.cpp)

Comment: please show a [mre]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.